# In SQL Where if date then compare dateColumn1 else compare with dateColumn2

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, where-clause

Don't really know what could be the best title regards my problem.
I don't even know if this could be possible. I will take every chance I have.

Let's go with my problem.
i have @dateStart and @dateEnd
then I have 2 columns for date.
let's name it for example dateCol1 and dateCol2
Is it possible to create a condition on

```
Select * From table Where
```

case 1 if @dateStart is greater to sample date '1/01/2014' then it would push to the condition

```
dateCol1 between @dateStart and @dateEnd
```

else if @dateStart is less than that date i could have a condition of

```
dateCol2 between @dateStart and @dateEnd
```

I'm Not really good in SQL, so I would be really thankful if someone could help me here.
by the way I'm using microsoft SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select * From table Where case when @dateStart > '1/01/2014' then dateCol1 else dateCol2 end
between @dateStart and @dateEnd
```

try this solution

Answer (score 1):

Use CASE WHEN... ELSE

```
 CASE
   WHEN Boolean_expression THEN.       
 result_expression [ ...n ] 
   [ ELSE else_result_expression ] 
END
```